# VBA vlookup/group by to jagged array

Tags: vba, excel, jagged-arrays

Say I have two columns `A`and `B` in my spreadsheet:

```
A       B
0.2     1
0.0     1
0.5     2
0.7     3
1.5     3
2.7     3
0.1     4
```

How do I convert this to a jagged array based on the value of `B` such that

```
arr = [[0.2, 0.0],
       [0.5],
       [0.7, 1.5, 2.7],
       [0.1]]
```

Comment: Kindly have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846060/excel-vba-sorting-arrays-by-comparing-their-2nd-index-number/15847460#15847460

Comment: I don't think it is posible, what dimensions would your arr have?

Comment: @Juliusz is correct, it's not possible to create an array with those dimensions. You can, however, store a `Collection` of arrays.

Comment: It would be possible to store it as a Variant (like an array of arrays). The dimension would be the number of unique items in B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
Dim uniqueT() As Variant: uniqueT = DistinctValues(Application.Transpose(Range("arrT")))
Dim nMaturities As Integer: nMaturities = UBound(uniqueT)
Dim nKnots As Integer, row As Integer

Dim K() As Variant: ReDim K(1 To nMaturities)
Dim mids() As Variant: ReDim mids(1 To nMaturities)

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To nMaturities
        nKnots = .CountIf(Range("arrT"), "=" & uniqueT(i))
        row = .Match(uniqueT(i), Range("arrT"), False) - 1
        K(i) = .Transpose(Range("arrK").Cells(1).Offset(row, 0).Resize(nKnots, 1))
        mids(i) = .Transpose(Range("arrMid").Cells(1).Offset(row, 0).Resize(nKnots, 1))
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll  get a jagged array but the below will give you space fot the maximum number and blanks if there is no values.

```
Sub jag_array()

    Dim maxcolb As Long, countcolb As Long, arr() As Variant
    maxcolb = Application.Max(Columns(2))
    countcolb = 1

    ReDim arr(1 To maxcolb, 1 To countcolb) As Variant
    'cycle through all values eg 1 to 4
    For i = 1 To maxcolb

        'expand the array as required
        If Application.CountIf(Columns(2), i) > countcolb Then

            countcolb = Application.CountIf(Columns(2), i)
            ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To countcolb) As Variant


        End If

        'find and cycle through all found column b
        Set c = Columns(2).Find(i, After:=Cells(1, 2), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then

            j = 1
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                'add column a value
                arr(i, j) = Cells(c.Row, 1).Value
                j = j + 1
                Set c = Columns(2).FindNext(c)

                If c Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    Next

'use arr(x, y) as you need to

End Sub
```

Comment: @Morten, FYI I've just tested my code and improved a few bugs!